# How to print elements of two char arrays in a specific way?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

Input:

```
2,3,1
5,2,3
```

Expected Output:

```
2,5,3,2,1,3
```

All digits should be separated with a comma.

My code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
    char[] elms1 = input1.toCharArray();

    String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
    char[] elms2 = input2.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < elms1.length; i++)
        System.out.print(elms1[i] + "," + elms2[i]);
}
```

Alas, it outputs an unexpected result with extra commas and it looks like:

Input:

```
2,3,1
5,2,3
```

My Output is:

```
2,5,,,3,2,,,1,3
```

How can I eliminate extra commas to get the right output?

Comment: The code is fine you are taking the input as a line so the char array is {'2', ',', '3', ',' '1', ','}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you convert `2,3,1` to a character array, you obviously get an array of `[2, comma, 3, comma, 1]` so your output isn't unexpected. What you're probably looking for is the `String.split` method, which you can use to split *by the comma*. I'm not sure why you're trying to convert into characters in the first place, what about a 2 digit number?

Comment: You can also change your print statement to `System.out.print(elms1[i]+elms1[i+1]+","+elms2[i]+elms2[i+1]);` and with i increment by 2 as `i+=2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
List<Integer> elms1 = Arrays.stream(input1.split(",")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
List<Integer> elms2 = Arrays.stream(input2.split(",")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i = 0; i < elms1.size()-1; i++) {
    System.out.print(elms1.get(i) + "," + elms2.get(i) + ",");
}

System.out.print(elms1.get(elms1.size()-1) + "," + elms2.get(elms1.size()-1));
```

Output (based on your input):

```
2,5,3,2,1,3
```

Comment: The only code that passed all tests was yours. I learned something new today, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to just make a little change in your print statement as:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < elms1.length; i++) {
    if (i == elms1.length - 1) {
        System.out.print(elms1[i] + "," + elms2[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.print(elms1[i] + "," + elms2[i] + ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed your FOR loop iteration to i+=2 and it works smoothly. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your print statement for your current code which would take 2 characters from each array at a time considering commas to be a valid character input. Here's your code fix:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < elms1.length; i += 2) {
    if (i == elms1.length - 1)
        System.out.print(elms1[i]+","+elms2[i]);
    else
        System.out.print(elms1[i]+""+elms1[i+1]+""+elms2[i]+""+elms2[i+1]);
}
```